Correct param decorator usage
I am wondering if I am implementing correctly a controller action to parse a parameter from URL in Nest.js
In my AppController class I declared a function getUser
@Get('user/:id')
  async getUser(@Param('id') id:string): Promise<users>{
    return await this.prismaService.getUser(parseInt(id));
  }

The part that bugs me is the parseInt(id), is there a way to declare it as
@Get('user/:id')
  async getUser(@Param('id') id:number): Promise<users>{
    return await this.prismaService.getUser(id);
  }
 

And avoid parsing the int from the string, enforcing typing at a different level instead of handling parseInt errors?
Right now my problem is that if I declare it as shown and call the route with http://localhost:3000/user/1, the id parameter is still a string (a bit confusing for me since in the function signature it is a number and I was expecting it to throw an error at compile time or parse me a number already).


The browser does not run your Typescript, it runs the JavaScript that the Typescript compiler generates. Typescript does not mean that it enforces the browser to do anything - it only enforces the developer. Your expectations are wrong.

"I was expecting it to throw and error at compile time or parse me a number already" seems to be pretty solid of a statement in that direction, what is wrong with that? Plus this code is server side, only the get call is executed browser side.

No matter how "solid" your statement is in your eyes, it is still based on wrong expectations. Again: Using Typescript does not mean that the browser will do something for you automatically ("... parse me a number already"), nor that the compiler will error out if you tell it wrong types - for the compiler, the types do line up: prismaService.getUser expects a Number and you tell the compiler that you do pass it the Number that getUser receives, so why should it complain? In reality though, getUser does not receive a Number.

I see what you mean now, I expected the @Params decorator to be type checked as well in respect to the getUser arguments, since I was declaring the  signature of the function with a type, but I understand that the "number" type is only useful from the function body onwards

Typescript is only a tool to help the developer during development and build time. It, unfortunately, doesn't do much to enforce parameters at runtime. For that, you could use the ParseIntPipe from Nest, @Param('id', new ParseIntPipe()) id: number and if you pass something that isn't a number it will error, or you could go the full validation route and create a DTO.
